# Ruby: How to solve a simple grep function using regular expression?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find a way to solve this:

> Implement a simple grep function that takes a string x as input, and prints the lines of a file having any occurrences of string x anywhere in a line. You need to do a simple regular expression match after reading lines from a file. The output should also include the line numbers.

Here is a sample of the code I have written.  NOTE: I did not create a function just yet, I first need to get the code to recognize the file and display the corresponding message.

```
x=/you/

aFile = File.open("filename1.txt", "r") 

a = "" 

aFile.each {|line|
    a << line
}

sentence = a.split(".")

puts sentence

if sentence=~x
    puts "yes"
else
    puts "no"
end


aFile.close
```

And here is the contents of filename1.txt:

```
See you tomorrow. Have a good day Mr. Jones. See you tomorrow. Have a good 
day. See you tomorrow. See you tomorrow.
```

I can display the file but cannot compare it to a regular expression.  It has been printing out an error when I try to compare it. Could someone point out the error in my code and help me find the solution to my problem?

Comment: "It has been printing out an error" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. What is the error? What trouble do you have with your code? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a precise specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, and edge cases?

Comment: "A grep function" is the method [Enumerable#grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep). You are asked to use that method but have not done so. You want to read the file into an array `a` and then invoke `a.grep(s)`, where `s` is the given string to match, to extract (to a new array) those elements (lines) of `a` that contain the substring `s`.

Answer (score 1):

The results are unexpected since `sentence` is an array. I'm not sure what error you might be getting, but the result I get is a single 'no' response. To see the results for each individual sentence, you need to use a loop:

```
sentence.each do |s|
  puts s
  if s =~ x
    puts "yes"
  else
    puts "no"
  end
end
```

That produces the following results:

```
See you tomorrow
yes
 Have a good day Mr
no
 Jones
no
 See you tomorrow
yes
 Have a good 
day
no
 See you tomorrow
yes
 See you tomorrow
yes

no
```

The final result occurs because `split` inserts an element in the array for both sides of the separator. The final sentence doesn't have anything after it, so the `split` method adds an empty string to the array.

Notice there's also a problem extracting sentences using periods when the period is used for an abbreviation ("Mr. Jones"). It also wouldn't work for sentences that end with a question or exclamation mark. Finally, ellipsis will add *4 sentences* with this technique!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method like this and pass the word and file name. NOTE: you have to handle exceptions appropriately. The method will return actual line number with content containing the word.

```
  def search_word_in_file(word, file_name)
    regex = Regexp.new(word, "gi") # you may get rid of gi if you want exact match
    lines_with_number = {}
    f = File.open(file_name, 'r')
    f.each_line.with_index do |line, index|
      actual_line_number = index + 1
      if (regex).match(line)
        lines_with_number[actual_line_number] ||= []
        lines_with_number[actual_line_number] << line
      end
    end
    f.close
    lines_with_number
  end
```

So,

```
search_word_in_file('you', 'filename1.txt')
```

should work